# laptop monitor brightness always maximum upon charging

Tags: laptop, power-management, brightness

My laptop monitor brightness is set to maximum whenever I connect it to charging. I have gone to the brightness settings and changed this, but the problem repeats when I charge my laptop again...what is the best way I can solve this issue...

I would prefer some shell based solution if there is no way to fix this issue. Some of the requirements for such a program would be:

- It should detect when laptop is being charged and when the brightness goes to maximum, it should reduce it.
- Must be able to manually change the brightness if required
- Must have a configuration I can change

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the brightness of you screen by manually is xbacklight is requied open your terminal and type this

> sudo apt-get install xbacklight

and then type

> xbacklight -set 50

there 50 stands for brightness range we can get it upto 100 from 0. 
you can also increase and decrease the brightness from present value to specified level.as you mentioned if you want to increase to 10% from current value of brightness then should give this

> xbacklight -inc 10

to decrease

> xbacklight -inc 10

Refer this web page is one of the way to reduce brightness manually
(http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/) 
or
try this In some cases the brightness may be controlled from

> /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

as is the case with dell vostro 3400 and the brightness range is 0-15. You may  have to look for other folder in

> /sys/class

if the same path may doesnot exit.